# Can a @classmethod modify the record it creates in GAE?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Updates to an entity within the @classmethod that created it are not reliably persisted in the datastore.

My create method is below.  The parameter is the object to be persisted.

```
@classmethod
    def create(cls, obj):
        """Factory method for a new system entity using an System instance. Returns a System object (representation) including the meta_key."""        
        if isinstance(obj, System):
            pass
        else:
            raise Exception('Object is not of type System.')

        #check for duplicates
        q = dbSystem.all(keys_only=True)
        q.filter('meta_guid = ', obj.meta_guid)
        if q.get(): #match exists already
            raise Exception('dbSystem with this meta_guid already exists.  Cannot create.')                    


        # store stub so we can get the key
        act = cls(
                meta_status = obj.meta_status,
                meta_type = obj.meta_type,
                meta_guid = obj.meta_guid,
                json = None, 
                lastupdated=datetime.datetime.now())              
        act.put()

        # get the key for the datastore entity and add it to the representation
        newkey = str(act.key())

        # update our representation
        obj.meta_key = newkey

        # store the representation
        act.json = jsonpickle.encode(obj)
        act.put()

        return(obj)  #return the representation
```

My unittest tests confirm the returned object has a meta_key, and that the json for the associated entity is not none:

```
self.assertIsNotNone(systemmodel.dbSystem().get(s.meta_key).json) #json is not empty
```

However, when running my app on the development server, I find that the json field is intermittently NULL when this entity is retrieved later.

I have spent some time researching the datastore model, trying to find something that could explain the inconsistenent results, with no luck.  Two key sources are the [model class](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass#Model_put) and a really good [overview of the App Engine datastore](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Concepts) I found on Google code.

Can anyone confirm whether updates to an entity within the @classmethod that created it should be considered reliable?  Is there a better way to persist a representation of an object?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is likely this line:

```
q = dbSystem.all(keys_only=True)
```

You haven't said what `dbSystem` is but if it does an app engine query, then you are not guaranteed to get the most recent version of an object, and you could get an older version.

Instead, you should get the object by its key, which will guarantee that you get the most recent version.  Something like this:

```
q = dbSystem.get(obj.key())
```

Check out the app engine docs for getting an object by its key.

Comment: Kekito - thanks for the response.  At that point in the method, I don't know the key yet, as the object hasn't been created. In any case, that duplicate check seems to work ok.  It seems like the problem is with the second 'act.put()'; it doesn't always save the entity...